# How do I handle a string that has all 3 type of quotes? ("", '', ``)?

Tags: bash, escaping, github-actions, quotes

I know you normally would escape the quotes, but that is not an option in this case.

This issue is happening to me in a GitHub Action where I'm trying to use:
`${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_commit.message }}` which sometimes contains all types of quotes and parts of the string are attempted to run as commands due to that.

so if try something like: `echo "${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_commit.message }}" >> tmp.txt` and the string has `""` in it, there's a good chance it will break the command.
What can I do?

I've tried:

```
echo "${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_commit.message }}" >> tmp.txt
echo '${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_commit.message }}' >> tmp.txt
echo `${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_commit.message }}` >> tmp.txt
echo `"'${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_commit.message }}'"` >> tmp.txt
echo ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_commit.message }} >> tmp.txt
echo \'${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_commit.message }}\' >> tmp.txt
```

I expected the command to run successfully and save the variable contents to tmp.txt

Comment: Post a sample of the message so we can try on our side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [here-document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents):

```
cat <<'EOF' >>tmp.txt
${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_commit.message }}
EOF
```

With the first `EOF` quoted, the shell will not interpret or modify the here-document body, it will be appended to `tmp.txt` verbatim.